# How can I change lsblk to show model by default?

Tags: shell, command, lsblk

I'm currently running Arch.  I simply want to change `lsblk` to always display as if the`-o model` was selected in addition to the standard options.  I suppose I could rename `lsblk` and put a copy in the folder that would call it with that option, but that would mess up passing other arguments as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to rename, copy... just:

```
alias lsblk='lsblk -o model'
```

so every time you run `lsblk` you have the output of `lsblk -o model`

[EDIT]
I misunderstood the question, for which I propose the following solution.
you can create a function, let's call it `lsbk`, to do what is required:

```
lsbk() { lsblk  $@ -o +model; }
```

You should keep the -o option model also passing other parameters

Comment: @don_crissti I'm sorry, you're right, I misunderstood the question. Now edit the answer, it could be a solution ...

Comment: So alias is something I should check into, with the + modifier.  I understand its a bit limiting if I want to use other options.  If I need to revert I can just edit ~/.bashrc right?  Awesome, thanks.
EDIT: just saw your edit, would a function be specifically for a script?

Comment: you have to edit .bashrc or .bash_aliases.